# Migrating a simple Robotlegs application (form 1.5 to 2)

Tags: actionscript-3, mxml, robotlegs

I'm new to Robotlegs, and somewhat struggling with the first steps. 
To learn the ropes I followed the first part of [Joel Hooks' introduction](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/articles/intro-robotlegs-pt1.html) and am now trying to create the same in RL2.

My current questions/problems are:

- Which method has replaced the startup() in the Context
- In the Context I can no longer just use "mediatorMap"; Do I need to create a MediatorMap Instance for this?
- In the few RL2 example out there, many devs use the IConfig to configure their main Context; is this required, a good convention or optional.
- ..and in which way, is the Context 'configured' through this?

I spent the best part of the day looking for solutions. I apologize if I missed the obvious. 
Thanks in advance for any incite.

part of the main class (mxml)

```
xmlns:context="contexts.*"
    <fx:Declarations>
        <rl:ContextBuilder>
            <context:HelloWorldContext/>
        </rl:ContextBuilder>
</fx:Declarations>
```

and the (non-compling) context .as

```
public class HelloWorldContext extends Context
{       
    public function HelloWorldContext()
    {
        this.install(MVCSBundle);
        this.configure(HelloWorldConfig);

        mediatorMap.map(ButtonView).toMediator(ButtonMediator); // Error: mediatorMap not defined
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Which method has replaced the startup() in the Context In the Context

use `context.install` to install extension that you want to use.
most common one is `MVCSBundle`.
use `context.configure` with `(new ContextView)` argument will start your context initialization.

> I can no longer just use "mediatorMap"; Do I need to create a
>   MediatorMap Instance for this? 
>   you can inject IMediatorMap anywhere you need it, like in config
>       [Inject]
>       public var injector:IInjector;

```
[Inject]
public var mediatorMap:IMediatorMap;

[Inject]
public var commandMap:ISignalCommandMap;
```

> In the few RL2 example out there, many
>   devs use the IConfig to configure their main Context; is this
>   required, a good convention or optional. ..and in which way, is the
>   Context 'configured' through this?
>   you can create your own config. Usually, in there you will map your commands, mediators and injections. You create one [PostConstruct] method which will call all theese stuff:

If you implement IConfig inside config, you dont need [PostConstruct] tag, because robotlegs will call configure function automatically once the dependencies have been injected.

```
    [PostConstruct]
    public function init():void {

        context.logLevel = LogLevel.DEBUG;
//        injector.fallbackProvider = new DefaultFallbackProvider();

        mapSignalCommands();
        mapMediators();
        mapInjection();

        context.afterInitializing(afterInit);

    }
```

in your case you will have

```
_context:IContext;
public function MainApp()
{
    _context = new Context();
    _context.install(MVCSBundle);
    _context.configure(HelloWorldConfig,new ContextView(this));

        }
```

mediator thing goes to config on mapMediators();